# Which version of RenderScript should I be using?

Tags: android, renderscript

This is my gradle file in AndroidStudio:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //renderscriptTargetApi 21
        //renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Now if you check this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis)

It says:

> We recommend you set this value to the highest available API level
>   and set renderscriptSupportModeEnabled to true.

What is the highest API Level Available? is it 22? 18? 19? Where can I find out? I know 19 works because I tried it, in another app, I was just wondering which one is hte latest I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be just arbitrarily setting the highest API level. The docs are wrong and I just filed a bug to get that cleaned up internally. You should be setting it to the API level that your app is targeting. If you need to raise it for additional RenderScript functionality, it will be noted in the docs (i.e. this API only shows up in v19 -> set to 19). If you don't think you need much beyond the basic support library and runtime, please try to use 18 in general.

Comment: I don't get it, if you say " You should be setting it to the API level that your app is targeting." then it should be 22 right? The problem is that I am using a kitkat device for testing so, the support library should kick in right ?